# Find classes implementing a generic class using a Type 'x' as the generic type argument

Tags: c#, generics, reflection

I have an interface for defining events with some implementations

```
public interface IEvent {...}
public sealed class OrderPersisted : IEvent {...}
```

and an interface for handling these events with implementations through an abstract generic intermediate class :

```
public interface IEventHandler {...}
public abstract class EventHandlerBase<TEvent> : IEventHandler where TEvent : IEvent {...}
//The following event handler uses the OrderPersisted event as the generic type argument.
public sealed class OrderPersistedEventHandler : EventHandlerBase<OrderPersisted> {...}
```

What I'm trying to achieve is figuring out, using reflection, what event handlers use a certain concrete event of type 'X' as the generic type argument to implement the `EventHandlerBase<>` class. Something that would go like the following maybe :

```
foreach(var eventType in myAssembliesConcreteEventTypes)
{
    myEventTypesDictionary[eventType] = 
    exportedTypesOfMyAssembly.Where(/*-- implements EventBase with eventType --*/)
}
```

Thanks in advance.

### EDIT

The following worked for me

```
foreach(var eventType in myAssembliesConcreteEventTypes)
{
    myEventTypesDictionary[eventType] = exportedTypesOfMyAssembly
        .Where(t => t.BaseType.GenericTypeArguments.Any(gta => gta == type))
        .Select(t=>(IEventHandler)Activator.CreateInstance(t))
        .ToList();
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var opType = typeof(OrderPersisted);//Your choice
var myType = typeof (EventHandlerBase<>).MakeGenericType(opType);
var myExpectedTypes = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly()
    .GetTypes()
    .Where(x => x.IsSubclassOf(myType))
    .ToArray();
```

I reflected through `Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly()` you can replace that with your interested assembly. `IsSubclassOf` is what  you basically need.

Comment: the event type is something dynamic I can't just use `typeof(EventHandlerBase<OrderPersisted>)` , I have other events in my assembly. As you notice I'm iteration over `myAssembliesConcreteEventTypes` which i acquire dynamically.

Comment: Now it makes sense, but still I'm not that comfortable with that `MakeGenericType` call.

Comment: It is not that hard. `typeof (EventHandlerBase<>)` will return `EventHandlerBase<T>` we're just asking the runtime *heyy just make a concrete type for me with type argument `OrderPersisted`* Does that makes sense?

Comment: I meant performance wise, why would I create a type which I already have and which I can just select in a query?

Comment: No, you're not creating new type instance I believe. runtime will return same reference. You can test this via this code `var opType = typeof(OrderPersisted);
            var myType = typeof (EventHandlerBase<>).MakeGenericType(opType);
            var myType2 = typeof (EventHandlerBase<OrderPersisted>);
            bool sameReference = object.ReferenceEquals(myType, myType2);`